# Copy relevant rows and paste to new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple sheets which I am looking to copy and paste the relevant cells from rows into a new worksheet.  The defining factor is whether the rows are "Live" which is determined by whether today falls between the "start date" and "end date" columns. For all rows that are "live" certain cells on that row should then be copy pasted to the bottom of the list on the new worksheet.  I would then repeat these steps for the other worksheets so that the new worksheet essentially contains a summary of all "live" lines from the other sheets.

I then ultimately need to create a button so I can re-run this at the end of each day.

Hoping you can help!

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? [It appears you have made no attempt at all](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0):

You've defined and explained what you want to do nicely. So the next step would be to start researching the actions you want the code to do:

Start with how to copy rows:
http://www.bluepecantraining.com/copying-moving-rows-columns-excel-vba/

Next is how to find the last used row in a worksheet:
https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-last-row/

Next is to apply your condition on what rows to copy:
[Using VBA to check if a date is between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495266/using-vba-to-check-if-a-date-is-between-two-dates)

Next is how to create a `for loop` that runs the code the desired number of times:
https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html (a tip is to use the `LastRow` that you defined via the second link i posted. eg: "`For x  = 1 To LastRow`")

And lastly is how to assign a macro to a button or shape:
https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/how-to-assign-a-macro-to-a-shape-in-excel/

Try to build a code with the help of these links. If you get stuck, come back and show us what you've created and where the problem is. I (aswell as and many others) would love to help you on from there.